# Remove individually send button of jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I want to use jQuery File Upload but I see that every file gets added a button to make the climb independently. I wish I could remove that button to upload the files all at once when I press on submit button.

I tried to remove "to gross" but gives trouble code. And looking at the options do not find the option to remove that option. I don't want to simply hide css

I would also add to each file a input text and a textarea.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should really share what you have tried. A jsfiddle could be a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro this thread, but it was a top google result - The answer your looking for is simply setting AutoUpload from False to True. So many people try to bypass this, when a simple false to true fixes it.

```
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$/i
```